# Remove with entitymanager sometimes fails

Tags: java, database, postgresql, eclipselink, persistent

I've a problem with removing persisted objects from my database.I have some tables with bidirectional relationships between them. I've a test for removing an object that is still referenced by an other object and this is sometimes fails. I cannot figure out why it is.

My relationships look like this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Application.class, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = ModelConstants.ID_APPLICATION, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Application application;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Clazz.class, mappedBy = "pakage")
private List<Clazz> clazzes;
```

Do you have any idea, why I cannot remove a row through EntityManager?

My test:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteMethodReferencedByMethodCall() {
    Application application = new Application("", "testApplication");
    Pakage pakage = new Pakage("", "testPakage", application);
    Clazz clazz = new Clazz("", "testClazz", pakage);
    Method methodCaller = new Method("testFirstMethod", "testMethodFirst",
    clazz);
    Method methodCalled = new Method("testSecondMethod", "testMethodSecond",
    clazz);
    MethodCall methodCall = new MethodCall(methodCaller, methodCalled);
    DatabaseUtils.persistObject(entityManager, methodCall);

    assertEquals(2, getCountRows("m", entityMethod));
    assertEquals(1, getCountRows("mc", entityMethodCall));

    DatabaseUtils.removeObject(entityManager, methodCall);
    assertEquals(0, getCountRows("m", entityMethod));
    assertEquals(0, getCountRows("mc", entityMethodCall));
}
```

RemoveObject:

```
public static void removeObject(EntityManager entityManager,
  DatabaseElement databaseElement) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(databaseElement);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Exception:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "pakage" violates foreign key constraint "fk_clazz_id_pakage" on table "clazz"
Detail: Key (id_pakage)=() is still referenced from table "clazz".
Error Code: 0
Call: DELETE FROM public.pakage WHERE (id_pakage = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(Pakage[id_pakage = , name_pakage = testPakage, Application[id_application = , name_application = testApplication]]) at
```

Comment: could you post the exception and your test implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: If I call a refresh on the object before remove then everything works fine.

Like this:

```
entityManager.refresh(databaseElement);
entityManager.remove(databaseElement);
```

Maybe some caching works in the back ground and sometimes I had the correct associations in the object and sometimes not but I'm not sure.

Comment: You must maintain both sides of your bidirectional relationships to keep the cache insync with the database.